# Samsung range blew the breaker

Tags: electrical, kitchens

Stove popped and circuit breaker tripped unscrewed the back and where there is a red and white wires plugged into something has black burn marks around, any idea.

Comment: Please revise to add punctuation and capitalization to your one long sentence. A little respect for your readers goes a long way.

Comment: Upload pictures of the red/white wires, burn marks, etc. Plus model # of stove, and size of circuit (which you can get from the circuit breaker).

Comment: Go shopping for a new, or new-to-you-used, range, unless it's under warranty. Failure conditions that actually cause a typical range breaker to blow are ***severe*** and involve a lot of damage.

Comment: Pictures are definitely required here. There are too many possible problems to speculate and the wrong suggestion could start a fire.

Comment: Can you *please* post photos of what's going on, as well as the model of the range involved?

Comment: cause: something is wrong with your samsung range. probably the part that has burn masks is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Electric ranges have heating elements. As these elements age sometimes they short out and cause the breaker to trip. With the high current from a shorted element failure the wiring can be damaged. Photos are usually helpful and in this case a basic multi meter that measures voltage and resistance (continuity/ ohms) will be needed to troubleshoot the failure. If you want to repair we can assist but a photo of the damage will be needed and a meter to figure out what the cause was.